# "by" searching or "with" searching?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to say

> Having done some googling and searching, we understand it is a British firm- more precisely “It is the largest airline of the United Kingdom, measured by number of passengers carried, operating domestic and international scheduled services on over 600 routes in 32 countries”

Which is better to say "with some searching", "by some searching", "having done some not deep searches"? I like it to me academic and formal?

Comment: After some investigation, [we have determined]/[it was determined] ...

Comment: very nice. Could you tell me Which is right ,Jim, by some searching or with some searching? @Jim

Comment: I wouldn't use either.  If forced to use *searching* I'd say, *After some searching*

Comment: If you forced me to pick one of the two, I'd pick *with*, although I'd prefer to phrase it differently.  Since you want "academic and formal", I suggest you go with Jim's version.

Comment: After searching.  Or after searching a bit. Or after searching for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can also say the following instead of "Having done some googling and searching"

1.research on the internet
2. market research of the firm on the internet
3. Investigation and analysis via the internet

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may go with the version Jim stated. A little recommendation though...

> *After some searching on the Internet we learned/understood...* or *We searched on the Internet and learned/understood...*

I accept that *[Googling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google)* has become a verb now but since you want it for an academic purpose, prefer *searching on the Internet* and this will allow you to search on other resources such as Bing and Yahoo! as well!